# how to sort object in django

Tags: python, django

```
def bubble_sort(nts):
nts_len = len(nts)
for i in range(nts_len):
    for p in range(nts_len - i - 1):
        if nts[p] < nts[p+1]:
            t = nts[p]
            nts[p]= nts[p+1]
            nts[p+1] = t
return nts
def menu(request):
products = Product.objects.all()
if request.method == "POST":
    s = request.POST['select']
    if s == 'Price: Low to High':
        element = []
        for var in products:
            element.append(var)
        list_items = list(element)
        bb = bubble_sort(list_items)
        el = list(bb)
        print(el)
        
        pro = Product.objects.filter(id__in=bb)
        print(pro)
        products = bb

        # print(products)
```

**How to retrieve data from database in bubble sort for objects?TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Product' and 'Product'**

Comment: Why would you use bubble sort? TimSort is more efficient, and one normally orders in the database to do this in an efficient way.

Comment: are you sure your bubble sort is true?

Comment: Either compare the attributes from the Product instances or define the [rich comparison methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) in your class. Even better: Don't write a sort method yourself (you could use `sorted`) or fetch the data from the database in the correct order.

Comment: yes i want apply bubble sort on it

Answer (score 3):

You can user [order_by()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by):

```
Product.objects.all().order_by('field_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

your bubble sort looks wrong try this one:

```
def bubbleSort(lis):
    length = len(lis)
    for i in range(length):
        for j in range(length - i):
            a = lis[j]
            if a != lis[-1]:
                b = lis[j + 1]
                if a > b:
                    lis[j] = b
                    lis[j + 1] = a
    return lis
```

and you can sort by django ORM or SQL command like `order_by` `ASC` or `DESC`

Answer (score 0):

You use [order_by()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by)

```
# if you want products in ascending order by field_name
ordered_products = Product.objects.order_by('field_name')

# if your want products in descending order by field_name
ordered_products = Product.objects.order_by('-field_name')
```

Comment: yeh but i want to apply bubble sort on it

Comment: why do you want bubble sort